# Selecting phone number using contact card

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I would like to select a phone number from a contact with multiple phone numbers.
Can this be done through Android's own contact list?
I manage to list all my contacts with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);       
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

I choose, let's say, "John Doe" which, I know, has 3 phone numbers.
Is there anyway to make Android itself show me those 3 phone numbers to choose from using an intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let´s make the called for the picker

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Then in onActivityResult() let's check how many number has the selected contact, if number>1 then lets show a dialog to choose one:

```
Uri result = data.getData();
Log.v(TAG, "Got a result: " + result.toString());

// get the contact id from the Uri
String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

// query for phone numbers for the selected contact id
c = getContentResolver().query(
    Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
    Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
    new String[]{id}, null);

int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
int phoneType = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

if(c.getCount() > 1) { // contact has multiple phone numbers
    final CharSequence[] numbers = new CharSequence[c.getCount()];
    int i=0;
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        while(!c.isAfterLast()) { // for each phone number, add it to the numbers array
            String type = (String) Phone.getTypeLabel(this.getResources(), c.getInt(phoneType), ""); // insert a type string in front of the number
            String number = type + ": " + c.getString(phoneIdx);
            numbers[i++] = number;
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        // build and show a simple dialog that allows the user to select a number
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.select_contact_phone_number_and_type);
        builder.setItems(numbers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                String number = (String) numbers[item];
                int index = number.indexOf(":");
                number = number.substring(index + 2);
                loadContactInfo(number); // do something with the selected number
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setOwnerActivity(this);
        alert.show();

    } else Log.w(TAG, "No results");
} else if(c.getCount() == 1) {
    // contact has a single phone number, so there's no need to display a second dialog
}
```

Comment: but that requires me to "dig" for the number list myself. is it possible to have android doing it? i can show a list of all phone numbers inside my contact list (showing up 3 times John Doe if I have 3 phone numbers for him). but can i make it in such way where i tap John's name and then Android itself provides me with a list of all 3 of John's numbers for me to pick one? i know it's asking a lot... but it's so it always looks "good" on all API versions

Comment: Mmmmm, As well I know, there's not a built-in to do what you want, you can choose the contact with a picker, and it will return all the data from him, you will have to get all the numbers (if have more than 1) and then create code for selecting one, that's what I know

Comment: thanks anyway.
i'll wait one more day to see if anyone can come with a solution.
if not i will mark your answer as correct for doing what's possible. ;)